# Translating Assembly to C program

Tags: c, assembly, binary, gdb, hex

Here is the assembly code I'm looking at:

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp, %epb
sub    $0x18, %esp
movl   $0x804a170, 0x4(%esp)
mov    0x8(%ebp), %eax
mov    %eax, (%esp)
call   0x8048f9b <strings_not_equal>
test   %eax, %eax
je     0x8048f78 <phase_1+34>
call   0x8049198 <failed>
leave
ret
```

The goal is to give the function of the assembly the correct input as to jump to the function `phase_1+34`. So here is what I am interpreting so far:

The first two lines are set up code for the function. The first 'sub' line is allocating space by moving '%esp' downward to store arguments to call the `strings_not_equal` function. I think that the two arguments being passed to `strings_not_equal` are `0x804a170` and the input value. I assume that `<strings_not_equal>` will return 0 if the passed strings *are* equal. The `je` then checks to see if `%eax & %eax` is zero, which will only happen if `%eax = 0`. So basically, it seems that the input string just has to be equal to `0x804a170`.

Anyone see any flaws so far?

At this point, I'm stuck, and what I have tried isn't working. `0x804a170` in decimal is 134521200. But the function this is being passed to is expecting *strings*. So `0x804a170` should be converted to a string? and that string is what the input should be equal to?

I dunno. If anyone sees any flaws or can give me a pointer it is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`0x804a170` is a pointer to something considered a "string" by the runtime. Since you give no information about what it is, we can only guess it's either a pointer to the first character, followed by more characters and ending with a `0`, or it's a pointer to the first character, and the previous 1/2/4/8 bytes describe the length as an integer.

It's not a string itself.

Comment: Ah of course. So in gdb I can them use the `x` command to examine memory location `0x804a170`, which returns `0x20656854`. I am then confused by what you mean when you say "the previous 1/2/4/8 bytes describe the length as an integer". Previous to what? Previous to that memory location?

Comment: If what `0x804a170` points to is `0x20656854`, then this should be the first character in the string, yea? But how does this long of a hex digit translate to a single char?

Comment: @jphollowed - he means a pstring (pascal like string). If this was a pstring, then 0x804a170 points to a count of the number of characters in the string. The size of the count could be a byte, a short (16 bits), a long (32 bits), ... However, since you see 0x20656854 (reverse the bytes since its a little endian 32 bit integer), then it's most likely the first 4 bytes of a c type string (no count) = "The " .

Comment: This is what I got too, "The ", but it is not working either. Am I right in interpreting that all it wants me to do is input a string equal to `0x20656854`?

Comment: @rcgldr The answer was "The future will be better tomorrow.". If after using `x 0x804a170` I then use `x 0x804a174` I see the next 4 characters, and continue until the end of the sentence. But this was honestly luck. How could I have known how many memory addresses to continue examining? Just because it should have filled the 18-byte-wide gap that was allocated for the function call?

Comment: @jphollowed - Since the address is a fixed address (0x804a170) instead of an offset from the stack, it's probably a literal (could be static or global). Since it's a c string, you scan for a terminating zero. If the string was Unicode, then most every other byte would be zero and you'd look for double zero.

Answer (score 0):

Commented the code:

```
        push   %ebp                     ;function name is apparently phase_1
        mov    %esp, %epb
        sub    $0x18, %esp              ;allocate 24 bytes from stack
        movl   $0x804a170, 0x4(%esp)    ;[esp+4] = pointer to literal, static, or global string
        mov    0x8(%ebp), %eax          ;[esp  ] = [ebp + 8] (this and next instruction)
        mov    %eax, (%esp)
        call   0x8048f9b <strings_not_equal>
        test   %eax, %eax
        je     0x8048f78 <phase_1+34>   ;probably branches to next instruction after ret
        call   0x8049198 <failed>
        leave
        ret
        ...                             ;padding here, nop (0x90) or int 3 (0xcc) are common 
phase_1 + 34 ...                        ;continuation of phase_1
```